# Using getline() in C++

Tags: c++, string, getline

I have a problem using getline method to get a message that user types, I'm using something like:

```
string messageVar;
cout << "Type your message: ";
getline(cin, messageVar);
```

However, it's not stopping to get the output value, what's wrong with this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the three lines you show. You might want to edit your question to include some more context?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20getline%20skipping

Comment: Is this all of your code? Do you do anything with messageVar afterwards?

Comment: Most likely there's a `'\n'` left in the stream from previous input.

Comment: Yes, I register the value in a DB, I was using cin >> messageVar, but that's just catch "word by word" of sentence

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you're using `getline()` after `cin >> something`, you need to flush the newline character out of the buffer in between. You can do it by using `cin.ignore()`.

It would be something like this:

```
string messageVar;
cout << "Type your message: ";
cin.ignore(); 
getline(cin, messageVar);
```

This happens because the `>>` operator leaves a newline `\n` character in the input buffer. This may become a problem when you do unformatted input, like `getline()`, which reads input until a newline character is found. This happening, it will stop reading immediately, because of that `\n` that was left hanging there in your previous operation.

Comment: What is an "unformatted input" and how is it related to getline()?

Comment: Also, is there an alternative way to achieve same behavior as the code above without using the cin,cin.ignore(), and getline() functions?

Answer (score 6):

If you only have a single newline in the input, just doing

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

will work fine. It reads and discards the next character from the input.

But if you have anything else still in the input, besides the newline (for example, you read one word but the user entered two words), then you have to do

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

See e.g. [this reference of the `ignore` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

To be even more safe, do the second alternative above in a loop until [`gcount`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) returns zero.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems.  The one downside is that with `cin.ignore()`, you have to press enter 1 more time, which messes with the program.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){
.... example with file
     //input is a file
    if(input.is_open()){
        cin.ignore(1,'\n'); //it ignores everything after new line
        cin.getline(buffer,255); // save it in buffer
        input<<buffer; //save it in input(it's a file)
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I know I'm late but I hope this is useful.**
**Logic is for taking one line at a time if the user wants to enter many lines**

```
int main() 
{ 
int t;                    // no of lines user wants to enter
cin>>t;
string str;
cin.ignore();            // for clearing newline in cin
while(t--)
{
    getline(cin,str);    // accepting one line, getline is teminated when newline is found 
    cout<<str<<endl; 
}
return 0; 
}
```

*input* :

3

Government collage Berhampore

Serampore textile collage

Berhampore Serampore

*output* :

Government collage Berhampore

Serampore textile collage

Berhampore Serampore

Answer (score -1):

i think you are not pausing the program before it ended so the output you are putting after getting the inpus is not seeing on the screen right?

do:

```
getchar();
```

before the end of the program

Comment: I assume this answer is for Windows, which usually terminates the console upon return. I believe it does not apply to the question?

Answer (score -1):

The code is correct. The problem must lie somewhere else. Try the minimalistic example from the std::getline documentation.

```
main ()
{
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your full name: ";
    std::getline (std::cin,name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, the input is inserted into the `name` object, but I cannot use it to print the `hello name`. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, you can. I just tried it out and it works just fine. What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: No, this misses the point.  The problem, as described by people above is that when the getline() follows another input using cin there is still a newline in the input buffer.  The minimal example given has no input preceding the getline() and so of course it doesn't reproduce the issue that the original poster is asking about.