# Stringstream compile error after including header

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm trying to use a stringstream to read in a string and convert it to various other data types. However, I keep getting the error "Incomplete data type not allowed."

My research on this error has turned up precisely two fixes: make sure to include the header, and use std::stringstream instead of stringstream. Neither of those fixes helped me. Any ideas?

```
#include <sstream>

bool Arena::addFighter(string info){
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.getline(info);
    ...
}
```

Edit: The getline() is not the problem. The code is throwing errors when I try to declare the ss object.

Comment: Please provide the full error.

Comment: Intellisense: incomplete data type is not allowed.

Plus a whole bunch of errors coming from the sstream file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
ss.getline(info);
```

to this

```
getline(ss, info);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786575/using-getline-in-c) question for how to use `getline()`. Also check the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) before asking next time. :)

The error I got was this:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::getline(std::string&)’
     ss.getline(info);
```

---

If you are not using namespace std, then you should pass a `std::string` as an argument and not just a `string`.

Comment: That didn't change anything in my code. The error is occurring in the declaration of the ss object.

Comment: I am using namespace std. The reason I put that in front of the stringstream was because that was the answer given to some other people getting the same error. It didn't help my code at all.

Comment: Then @Michael, you should post some more code, a minimal example.

Comment: I solved my own problem. Before I included <sstream>, I included a header that defined a class. In that header, I forgot a semicolon at the end. (The error message for that was hidden in a whole bunch of other stuff.) Because of that, my build wasn't actually including <sstream>. Thanks for the help, everyone.