# C++ Structures: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved

Tags: c++, function, struct

I am trying to write a function that returns a `struct`. I keep getting an error that says:

> reference to overloaded function could not be resolved, Did you mean to call it?

Please help.

[image]

Comment: The reasons for these errors are most likely missing `#include` lines.  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please always add code as text, as opposed to code in an image.

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> endl` is a mistake. `endl` is only for outputting.

To consume up to the end of the line after reading, you can use:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

However for your program it is not necessary to do that. (Each `>>` reader you use consumes leading whitespace already).  So for this program you could just take out the `>> endl`.

Answer (score -3):

for 'cin', there is no overloaded operator to get 'string' datatype, but you can call getline(cin, employee.name) where getline is defined in

Comment: Have ever tried, what you are claiming. Your statement: _for `cin`, there is no overloaded function to get `string` datatype_ is completely wrong. Instead, `cin` cannot be used to take a `string` with spaces as input.

Comment: Ya, I proably wrong as I haven't try out what I wrote..Anyway, you can check  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786575/using-getline-in-c