# Have problems with string pointer

Tags: string, pointers, getline

`private:
    int Number;
    string *Name;
public:
    Mokhaberat()
    {
        Name = new string;
        cout<<"plz enter the name : ";
        getline(cin,*Name);
        cout<<"plz enter the Num : ";
        cin>>Number;
        cout<<"\n\n";
    }`

Hello guys ..
what is wrong with this line of my code --> getline(cin,*Name) ?
when the compiler comes for this line , it will pass and nothing will happen 
any answers ? Tnq :D
notice : i want spaces ,, that is why i used getline ,, and second reason : i want to use dynamic space

Comment: This does not show enough code to make it a MCV example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using getline() in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786575/using-getline-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the answer ..
i had to use cin.ignore() in order to clean the buffer ..
the reason that nothing happend when compiler read that function (getline) is the buffer ..
use cin.ignore () after your cin(s) then you good to go :D