# Qt logical error during getting user's input from terminal via getline function and writing it into a file

Tags: qt, getline, qfile

Using console, I want to write the desired user's input into a file via **getline**  function inside the ***wFile*** function and then read it. I face with logical error during Runtime; whatever I as user write doesn't type into the output terminal and it doesn't succeed more steps. Apparently **fwrite** function  with this feature in the libraries exists, but I want to write my own code differently this way. I think I must have neglected a point. Here's the code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <String>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void wFile(QString Filename)
{
QFile  mFile(Filename);
QTextStream str(&mFile);
qDebug() << "what do you want to write in the desired file: ";
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);
if (!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly  | QFile::Text))
{
    qDebug() << "could not open the file";
    return;
}
mFile.flush();
mFile.close();
}

void read (QString Filename){
QFile nFile(Filename);

if(!nFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
 {
     qDebug() << "could not open file for reading";
     return;
 }
QTextStream in(&nFile);
QString nText = in.readAll();
qDebug() << nText;
nFile.close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
QString nFilename ="P:/DocumentArminV.txt";
wFile(nFilename);
read(nFilename);
return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);` is it proper C++ to put a function declaration inside that scope area...?

Comment: dear @JohnLaw, I'm not completely sure whether it is proper to put the getline function's declaration inside that scope area or not.

Comment: Well, I'm no expert myself, but I've never seen anything like it. If you're using `getline`, directly pass the `istream` and `std::string` to receive input (e.g. `getline(std::cin, strBuff);`. Then maybe write strBuff into the qTextStream.

Comment: dear @JohnLaw, It gets "cin is not member of std" error. and I have already tried to write the strBuff (or my "str" buffer variable) into the QTextStream inside the wFile function code.

Comment: ... `std::cin` comes along with the `iostream` header file... you can guess my next question...

Comment: dear @JohnLaw, yes you're right I've neglected iostream, but I still have syntax error of: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istream&, QTextStream&)'
     getline(std::cin, str);

Comment: there's no overload for `getline(std::istream&, QTextStream&)`. Please check the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and at least do some preliminary research on how to use it ([SO thread on how to use std::getline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786575/using-getline-in-c)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoiler alarm: At the very end of this answer, there is a very simple recommendation for a fix.

## What OP did

Concerning `istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);` in `wFile(QString Filename)`:

This declares function `getline()` in function `wFile()`.

1. This is a valid declaration concerning C++.
2. Concerning the sample code, I missed the respective headers. IMHO,
   `#include <istream>` and
   `#include <string>`
   are required to make this compiling.
   However, it is possible that the existing `#include`s include them indirectly. So, OP's code may even compile without them.
3. Declaring functions, which are not used as well as re-declaring functions which are already declared is somehow useless but not wrong.

To demonstrate this, I made a small sample:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <istream>
#include <string>

void func()
{
  puts("in func()\n");
  std::istream& getline(std::istream&, std::string&);
  // Even duplicated prototyping is accepted without complaints:
  std::istream& getline(std::istream&, std::string&);
}

int main () 
{
  func();
  return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs perfectly.

Output:

```
in func()
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2810ddad83891e8)</kbd>

## What OP (probably) wanted

> Using console, I want to write the desired user's input into a file via getline function inside the wFile function and then read it.

This sounds a bit confusing to me. `std::getline(std::cin, )` can be used to *read* user input from console. May be, it's a bit bad wording only.

Assuming, the OP wanted to read input from console, obviously, declaring a function is not sufficient – it must be called to become effective:

```
#include <iostream>

void func()
{
  std::cout << "Enter file name: ";
  std::string fileName; std::getline(std::cin, fileName);
  std::cout << "Got file name '" << fileName << "'\n");
}

int main () 
{
  func();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter file name: test.txt↵
Got file name 'test.txt'
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c991351e4d90630)</kbd>

## C++ `std` vs. Qt

Qt is undoubtly built on top of the C++ `std` library. However, though it's possible it is not recommended to mix both APIs when it can be prevented (or there aren't specific reasons to do so).

Both, Qt and C++ `std`, are a possibility to write portable software.
Qt covers a lot of things which are provided in the std library as well but a lot of other things additionally which are not or not yet part of `std`. In some cases, the Qt is a bit less generic but more convenient though this is my personal opinion. IMHO, the following explains how I came to this:

## `std::string` vs. `QString`

`std::string` stores a sequence of `char`s. The meaning of `char`s when exposed as glyph (e.g. printing on console or displaying in a window) depends on the encoding which is used in this exposing. There are lot of encodings which interprete the numbers in the `char`s in distinct ways.

Example:

```
std::string text = "\xc3\xbc";
```

Decoded/displayed with

- [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252): `Ã¼`
- [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): `ü`

Based on character type of `std::string`, it is not possible to determine the encoding. Hence, an *additional hint* must be provided to decode this properly.

(AFAIK, it is similar for `std::wstring` and `wchar_t`.)

[`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) stores a sequence of [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters. So, one universal encoding was chosen by design to mitigate the "encoding hell".

As long as the program operates on `QString`, no encoding issues should be expected. The same is true when combining `QString` with other functions of Qt. However, it becomes a bit more complicated when "leaving the Qt universe" – e.g. storing contents of a `std::string` to `QString`.

This is the point where the programmer has to provide the *additional hint* for the encoding of the contents in `std::string`. `QString` provides a lot of `from...()` and `to...()` methods which can be used to re-encode contents but the application programmer is still responsible to chose the right one.

Assuming that the intended contents of `text` should have been the `ü` (i.e. UTF-8 encoding), this can be converted to `QString` (and back) by:

```
// std::string (UTF-8) -> QString
std::string text = "\xc3\xbc";
QString qText = QString::fromUtf8(text.c_str());
// QString -> std::string (UTF-8)
std::string text2 = qText.toUtf8();
```

---

This has to be considered when input from `std::cin` shall be passed to `QString`:

```
std::cout << "Enter file name: ";
std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);
QString qFileName = QString::fromLocal8Bit(input);
```

And even now, the code contains a little flaw – the locale of `std::cin` might have changed with [`std::ios::imbue()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue). I must admit that I cannot say much more about this. (In daily work, I try to prevent this topic at all e.g. by not relying on Console input which I consider especially critical on Windows – the OS on which we usually deploy to customers.)

Instead, a last note about OP's code:

## How to fix it

Remembering my above recommendation (not to mix std and Qt if not necessary), this can be done in Qt exclusively:

```
QTextStream qtin(stdin);
qtin.readline();
```

I must admit that I never did it by myself but found this in the Qt forum: [Re: stdin reading](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50214-stdin-reading?p=225624#post225624).

Comment: dear @Scheff! what a comprehensive perfect answer! thanks a lot. I understood my mistake, I just were mixing Qt liberaries with std. I mark it as answered perfectly:)