# How to fix the error of not taking value at 0 position in loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to take input from User in program But unable to take input at index 0

void User::call()
{
    `cout<< "number of times :";
    cin>>a;
    for (int i=0 ;i < a;i++)
    {
    cout<<"ENTER NAME : ";
    getline(cin,b);
    cin.ignore();
    }
}

`

I have attached the pictures of code and output result . Kindly check.
[MY CODE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5T9a.jpg) 
[AND OUTPUT HERE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq0Dv.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question, to include the copy-pasted [mcve], and input/output used, as text (not as images).

Comment: Don't post images of code here please.

Comment: Hello , i wasn't able to put the code ,that's why posting images . Kindly accept my Apology.

Comment: @BilalKhan "_i wasn't able to put the code ,that's why posting images_" I don't believe you. I have no problem in putting code in my questions/answers, so you shouldn't have any problems as well. In addition to that: you should've, at the very least, got a message, which stated the problem with your question, before posting it. You should've considered the suggestion (if any), before trying to workaround the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using getline() in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786575/using-getline-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18786719/499054). I think the issue is caused by a stay newline or carriage return character.

In your code, try changing:

`cin >> a` to the following:

```
cin >> a;
cin.ignore(); // ignore the stray newline after you input a number.
```

Comment: If the question is answered in another question, consider marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I'm not sure if it's a duplicate yet, since it's a little unclear of the exact issue OP is experiencing. Particularly, if it's an issue only when they enter in `0`, or if it's an issue with all numbers.

Comment: @KevinEvans : Error displaying after running your suggestion in code :  'std::string' has no member named 'ignore'

Comment: @BilalKhan Did you use the correct variable? You should be calling `.ignore()` on `cin`, not on `b`.

Comment: @KevinEvans , Thanks . Problem Solved within minutes

Comment: @BilalKhan Cool. Please marked the question as solved by pressing the checkbox to the right of the answer.

Comment: @KevinEvans , Also tell me what text i replace with cout and cin on stack overflow while posting the code . It is showing red line under cin and cout of my code while posting

Comment: @BilalKhan I'm not sure what your issue is when posting code to StackOverflow. You can post a screenshot of your error and post it to [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @KevinEvans , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694535/how-to-fix-the-error-of-not-taking-value-at-0-position-in-loop?answertab=votes#tab-top