# can I write character array ch[n] instead of ch[10]

Tags: c++

In my c++ code i want to write character array s[n] instead of writing s[10]. where n is size is the array, it is given by the user at the run time.
But its not taking input. Its only taking n, not string.

I got the Output like this,

Enter size : 10

Enter String :

String :

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstring>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       int n;
       cout<<"Enter size : ";
       cin>>n;
       char s[n];
       cout<<"Enter String : \n";
       cin.getline(s,n);
       cout<<"String : \n";
       int l=strlen(s);
       cout.write(s,l);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Variable length arrays (VLAs) are not part of the C++ language, although some compilers support them as an extension: [Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39334435/10871073).  But why are you using C-style strings in C++ - just use `std::string`, instead.

Comment: // you might consider using dynamic memory ....
      char* s = new char[n]; 
      cout << "\n  Enter chars    : ";
      cin.getline(s,n);  cin.ignore();
      cout << "     (  chars are: '" << s << "')";
 // use smart ptr OR remember to delete the allocation

Answer (score 5):

`cin.ignore()` can be used to patch your problem, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786575/using-getline-in-c):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter size : ";
    cin>>n; n++;
    char s[n];
    cout<<"Enter String : "; cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(s,n);
    cout<<"String : ";
    cout.write(s,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Enter size : 10
Enter String : 1234567890
String : 1234567890
```

*Note: Ran in `Code::Block 20.03, g++ version 6.3.0, Windows 10, 64 bit`.

But, as a comment mentioned above, `VLA`s or `Variable Length Array`(s) are **not** part of the standard in C++, *although* `g++` and `clang++` compiler support them.

And as @Kevin Pastor specified, the easiest way would be to use `std::string` that does all the work of data allocation.

Sample:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s; cout << "Your string: ";
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << "String: " << s;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Your string: 1234567890
String: 1234567890
```

More info [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334435/variable-length-array-vla-in-c-compilers) about VLAs.

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned in a comment, in C++, you cannot create a variable length array. This said, there's plenty of other ways you can address the problem. The easiest one would be to use `std::string` that does all the work of data allocation. If your situation requires you to use a `char` array, you could allocate some memory for an array as so: `char * s = new char[n];`. This would create a pointer to a memory location where `n` characters could be stored.

Comment: And, in full generality, if you need a dynamically-sized `T[]` for some type `T`, then `std::vector<T>` is the correct solution. `new T[]` is almost never what you actually want.

Comment: Or, use `malloc`.